# Bootstrap doesn't work while using Helmet

Tags: bootstrap-5, helmet.js

```
    app.use(helmet());

const scriptSrcUrls = [
    "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/",
    "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://kit.fontawesome.com/",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net",
];
const styleSrcUrls = [
    "https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/",
    "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/",
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/",
    "https://use.fontawesome.com/",
];
const connectSrcUrls = [
    "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://b.tiles.mapbox.com/",
    "https://events.mapbox.com/",
];
const fontSrcUrls = [];
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: [],
            connectSrc: ["'self'", ...connectSrcUrls],
            scriptSrc: ["'unsafe-inline'", "'self'", ...scriptSrcUrls],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", ...styleSrcUrls],
            workerSrc: ["'self'", "blob:"],
            objectSrc: [],
            imgSrc: [
                "'self'",
                "blob:",
                "data:",
                "https://res.cloudinary.com/sdfgsfgsssss/" 
                "https://images.unsplash.com/",
            ],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", ...fontSrcUrls],
        },
    })
);
```

I am getting these errors in the console

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/ https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/ https://api.mapbox.com/ https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com/". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

clusterMap.js:13 Map Loaded
campgrounds:1 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/ https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/ https://api.mapbox.com/ https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com/". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Does anyone know why I am getting these errors in the console
The whole website works but all the bootstrap styling has been disabled!
When I remove the npm helmet all the bootstrap loads again.

has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net` is not in your list of `style-src` directives.

```
const styleSrcUrls = [
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net",
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a simple fix